# Не работает анимация (animate) в Jquery

Tags: jquery, animate, html

Ребят, всем привет. Есть такой код.

Html

```
<div class="menu">
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_1_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_2_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_3_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_4_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_5_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_6_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_7_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_8_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_9_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_10_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_11_un.jpg"/></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/menu_12_un.jpg"/></a></div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){

    $('.menu div a').hover(function(){
                $(this).animate({
                    $(this).find('img').attr('src','img/menu_1.jpg') 
                }, 300);

        },

        function(){
                $(this).animate({
                    $(this).find('img').attr('src','img/menu_1_un.jpg')
                }, 300);

        });
        });
```

Хочу, чтобы при навидении на картинку она плавно менялась на другую (из чернобелой в цветную). Но что-то не фурычит скрипт. Ребзи, подскажите что и как?

Comment: Функция есть, вызова нет, добавьте к последним закрывающим скобкам вызов: `})();`

Comment: не понял? где неверно?

Comment: @duddeniska, вместо последних `});` нужно поставить то, что я написал, а вообще, чтобы не терять вызовы, пользуйтесь `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Comment: @MasterAlex к сожалению, не работает

Comment: @duddeniska, вообщем суть в том, что нельзя такое в animate передавать, там можно изменять только параметры css, а не параметры элемента, попробуйте менять изображение просто по hover, а анимацию можно и в css настроить, кстати изображение по hover, тоже можно в css менять :)

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос][1], там есть 2 варианта ответа с примерами кода, когда можно делать изображение чёрно-белым без использования JS.

[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/395147/

Answer (score 1):

У вас не валидный javascript в функцию `animate` передается объект, `{left: 10}` - например валидный объект. И что вы хотите в итоге ? Плавную смену картинки. Тогда Вам нужно сделать по другому: Показать две картинки друг над другом и плавно менять прозрачность верхней ...

```
$(function(){

    $('.menu div a').mouseenter(function(){
          $(this).find('img:first').animate({opacity:0}, 300);
    }).mouseout(function(){
          $(this).find('img:first').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
    });
 })();
```

А в идеале нужно реализовать через стили, скриптом такое делать не стоит.